# Retain client timezone when converting from JDateTime to timestamp

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, timestamp

I have a basic problem I am unfortunately unsure on.

Basically we're trying to create an interface in one application to another. For this to happen we are ripping out numerous fields from a database and converting these fields into a format the other application will accept.  So for example in this case we have a field of type JDatetime which we need to convert to Timestamp...easily done:

```
 Timestamp tradedate = new Timestamp(trade.getTradeDate().getTime());
 return tradedate;
```

However due to .getTime() returning the timestamp based on the system timezone, we have values which are of EST being returned with the time it would be in GMT.

My question is how can I simply retain the timezone of the field in question, with no conversion to GMT.  The system has values from all different timezones so I want to retain what is in the client data.

Haven't used Java or Eclipse in some time so teething troubles are ongoing!

Comment: I assume this is `JDateTime` from http://jodd.org/doc/jdatetime.html -  is it `java.sql.Timestamp` as well? If so, bear in mind that `Timestamp` has no concept of a time zone.

Comment: Sorry you are indeed correct that it has no concept of time zone and also on the nature of the types.  I suppose the issue is essentially already taken care of by converting everything to GMT but I think clients would freak out when comparing trades on the two platforms and seeing the difference in hours between two trades.